Low-prime intervals

$\mathbb P\ $ -- the set of all natural prime numbers.

$\mathbb N=\{1\,\ 2\,\ \ldots\}\ $ -- the set of all natural numbers.

$\forall_{d\, x\,\in\,\mathbb R_{_{>0}}}$, $E(d\ x) := \frac{\log(d)}{\log(x)} $ -- we will say that $\ E(d\ x)\ $ is the exponent of divisor $\,d\,$ with respect to $\,x\ $
(e.g. $E(d\,\ d^2) = \frac 12$).


Let $\ 1 < a < b\ $ and $\,\ a\,\ b\in\mathbb N.\ $ Define:
$$ M(a\,\ b)\ :=\ \max\left(\, E(p\,\ b):\ p\in\mathbb P\ \ \text{and}\ \ p\, | \prod_{x=a}^b x
\ \right) $$
The computational challenge:$\quad$ given real $\ f\in(0;1),\ $ find as long as possible intervals $\ [a;b]\ $ such that $\ M(a\ b)\le f.\ $ (A variation:
$\ \ldots M(a\ b)< f.)$
This implies a table of the record length results $\ L_f\ $ (and of $\ Ł_f$). One may also consider record results related to the positions of intervals $\ [a;b].$
One may also reverse the notion of records. We may fix the length $\ N:=b-a\ $ of the intervals $\ [a\,\ b]$, then we will be concerned with the respective minimal interval divisor exponents $\ F_N$.
The mathematical challenge: Given $\ f\in(0;1),\ $ are there only finitely many intervals $\ [a;b]\ $ as described above?
In either case, the question arises about the distribution of such intervals.



EXAMPLES
$$ M(8\,\ 9)\ =\ \frac 12\qquad\text{but}\qquad M(8\,\ 10)\ =\ \frac{\log(5)}{\log(10)}\ =
   \ 0.6989700\ldots $$
Next,
$$ M(63\,\ 64)\ =\ \frac{\log(7)}{\log(64)}\ =\ 0.467892\ldots\qquad\text{but}\qquad
   M(63\,\ 65)\ =\ \frac{\log(13)}{\log(65)}\ =\ 0.61673995\ldots $$
Next,
$$ M(98\,\ 100)\ =\ \frac{\log(11)}{\log(100)}\ =\ 0.5206963\ldots $$
-- not too bad but Dave Benson's examples are much-much better (see the comments below).

Well the maximum term occurs when $p$ is maximized, so the question is if there are long intervals $[a,b]$ such that the largest prime divisor of $\frac{b!}{(a-1)!}$ is $\le b^f$.

There are also a lot of detailed question. E.g. Is there a natural number $\ n>1\ $ such that $\ M(n-1\ \ n+1)\ \le \frac12\ ?$

My note is significantly related to a "Problem of Stormer" -- see paper "On a problem of Stormer" (1962) by D.H.Lehmer.

243024312432 only involves primes up to 19, and 1331013311113312 only involves primes up to 29.

175751757617577*17578 only involves primes up to 47.

58285829583058315832 only involves primes up to 67.

2803228033280342803528036*28037 only involves primes up to 163.

290783290784290785290786290787290788290789*290790 only involves primes up to 523.

Is it fair to interpret the question as asking for the behaviour of functions $a(x)$ such that for infinitely many $x$ there are intervals of the shape $[x - a(x), x]$ which consist of only $x^f$ smooth integers, for some $f \in (0,1)$?

I suppose the point of my examples was that your question in the comments about $M(n-1\ n+1)\leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ was not nearly bold enough. My last example was a sequence of eight consecutive integers with no prime divisors as large as the square root. I tried to find nine, but my computer got bored and started humming tunes from the Marriage of Figaro at me.

@DaveBenson, thank you for your examples. In my comment, I just wanted things to get rolling, I was not attempting a most ambitious conjecture. ******* Dave, you're very welcome to post your examples as, let people see partial progress. ******** In the light of your examples, the conjecture about arbitrary long $\ [a,\ b]\ $ such that $\ M(a,\ b)<\frac 12 $ is worth stating (it may go either way :) ).

Sloane's A355434 gives the beginnings of such sequences as follows: 1, 8, 48, 1518, 5828, 28032, 304260, 290783, 1255500, 4325170, 11135837, 18567909, 321903029, 1394350275, 287946949, 1659945758, 38882519234. So there are such sequences at least up to length 17. It doesn't indicate whether this goes on for ever, but I suspect it does.

Someone should mention the paper ON STRINGS OF CONSECUTIVE INTEGERS
WITH NO LARGE PRIME FACTORS, by Balog and Wooley. (One of their results: For each positive integer $k$ and each $\epsilon > 0$, there are infinitely many $n$ where none of $n+1, \dots, n+ k$ has a prime factor exceeding $n^\epsilon$.) The proof is reasonably elementary.

Oh, no, how could I forget the so familiar case of $\ M(48,\ 50) = \frac 12\ $ -- thank you, Dave.

@so-calledfriendDon That seems to settle the question completely! I'm surprised that it's "reasonably elementary" as you put it.

@DaveBenson "completely" -- actually, this opens a (positive!) Pandora's box.

I instantly upvoted @TheBestMagician comment, thus, let me mention -- using a Computer Science metaphor -- my q. was written in a higher-level language while their comment used assembler.

Let me attempt to turn my comment into an answer. The paper
Balog, Antal; Wooley, Trevor D., On strings of consecutive integers with no large prime factors, J. Aust. Math. Soc., Ser. A 64, No. 2, 266-276 (1998). ZBL0942.11041.
contains (a stronger version of) the  following result: For each positive integer $k$ and each $\epsilon > 0$, there are infinitely many $n$ where none of $n+1, \dots, n+k$ has a prime factor exceeding $n^\epsilon$.
Here's the seed of the idea. For 3 consecutive numbers, one can look at $x^m-1$, $x^m$, $x^m+1$, where $m$ is odd and has many small prime factors. Certainly $x^m$ has only small prime factors relative to its size. And $x^m-1$ and $x^m+1$ factor into cyclotomic polynomials of degree at most $\phi(m)$. So all the prime factors should be of size at most about $x^{\phi(m)}=(x^m)^{\phi(m)/m}$, and $\phi(m)/m$ can be made as small as one wants (by pumping $m$ full of small odd primes). Ultimately this comes down to the Euler's result that $\sum 1/p$ diverges.
It might seem we are stuck, because (e.g.) $x^m-2$ will not have such a nice factorization. But we are free to choose $x$. Suppose we try $x=2^a$. Then $x^m-2 = 2(2^{am-1}-1)$. If we pick $a$ appropriately, we can make $am-1$ also chock full of small primes (we can't get any of the primes appearing in $m$, but we can still put in enough to make sure the reciprocal sum of the primes dividing $am-1$ is large). Then $2^{am-1}-1$ will have only small prime factors relative to its size, for reasons like the last paragraph. And one can play similar games to extend the string to any length, but extracting a quantitative result (as in the Balog--Wooley paper) gets a bit messy.

Very nice explanation of the idea of the paper, avoiding the quantitative details.
